# "$request_headers" and "set_by_lua_block" not working after updating nginx version

Tags: nginx, version, request-headers

nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "set_by_lua_block" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf

"$request_headers" and "set_by_lua_block" not working after updating nginx version to nginx version: nginx/1.21.6

Comment: Maybe you were using dynamic lua-nginx-module and after nginx upgrade it can't be loaded anymore? In that case you'll need to upgrade/rebuild the module too,

Comment: How to upgrade/rebuild set_by_lua_block module, why "$request_headers"  is not working after updating nginx version to nginx/1.21.6

Comment: That depends on your environment. SO isn't a site to ask questions about building/installing software (unless you encounter some build error), check the module [homepage](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) for instructions. This kind of questions are to be asked at ServerFault.

Comment: @VishalReddy please show us output of `nginx -V` to find out if `lua` module was compiled in.

Comment: @user973254
nginx version: nginx/1.21.6
built by gcc 7.5.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
TLS SNI support enabled

Comment: configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp

Comment: --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream

Comment: @VishalReddy as you can see, there is NO `--add-module=/PATH_TO/lua-nginx-module` in your current `nginx` configuration

Comment: @user973254 thank you for the response. How and where to add this module in my current nginx configuration. because lua and request_header was working fine in previous nginx version 1.14

Comment: @VishalReddy you didn't provide any details of your OS, distribution, also, how did you install your previous `nginx` version? And latest? Was it some kind of upgrade or fully manual installation from source code?

Comment: @user973254 Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
Installed Nginx by using below command:
sudo apt-get install nginx -y

Comment: Updated Nginx Version to 1.21.6:
sudo wget https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key 
sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key 
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list  (add the below lines at the end of the file)    
deb https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ bionic nginx     
deb-src https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ bionic nginx 

sudo apt-get remove nginx-common -y
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nginx  -y
sudo systemctl restart nginx
Now check the nginx version

Comment: @VishalReddy I suppose, you need to install this Ubuntu package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libnginx-mod-http-lua

Comment: @user973254 I applied the methods but the problem is with the backward compatibility for lua with latest nginx version, There is no latest version of lua available

Comment: @VishalReddy There is an OpenResty bundle available for Ubuntu 18.04 bionic (its installation path and config files location may be different from the native nginx package): https://openresty.org/en/linux-packages.html#ubuntu